# Real Time Visitor Chat Pop Up?

Tags: livechat

Are there any PHP/JS based tools that allow me to intitiate a chat invitation to a live visitor on a site, like they do on Bank sites and Salesforce?

EDIT: LiveZilla could work, but I'm a Mac user, so I'd like to not have to run it via a VM. Is there any purely web based or mac-based solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

livezilla: http://www.livezilla.net/home/en/

I believe this would do what you want.

Comment: since John answered first, I'm giving him the up vote.

Comment: For some reason, it looked like pako had answered first. My bad. But I'm still looking for a Mac-friendlier solution, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try LiveZilla:

**http://www.livezilla.net/home/en/**

Here's a detailed list of features:

http://www.livezilla.net/features/en/

and some screenshots:

http://www.livezilla.net/screenshots/en/

Comment: Wait, dammit. There's no Mac compatible version?